# How to save push notification to Realm when app killed/background using swift

Tags: swift, realm, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I use the background to use `FCM` to push messages to the `iOS` device, I want to store the push information (using `Realm`).

There are only two cases that have a way to save successfully.

1.app running

2.app is killed/background, and click to push banner notifications
I hope I can do the app off/background and save it without having to click on the banner notification.

So I used the following method

1. Add Notification Service Extension in the project
2. Enable Background fetch/Remote notifications
3. Project and Notification Service Extension added to app groups

The next question arises. I used the same as `AppDelegates` in the `UNNotificationServiceExtension` to store the push code, but it didn't work. I looked at some related information. It seems that because Extension can't share Realm database, what should I do to let them share the data? ?

Or is my problem not in my narrative? Please have experienced people to guide me, thank you very much, my English is not good, if my question is not clear, please let me know.

Realm class

```
class Order: Object {

    @objc dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var amount = ""
    @objc dynamic var createDate = Date()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
class RealmDao: NSObject {

    static let shared = RealmDao()
    private var realm: Realm!

    private override init() {

        self.realm = try! Realm()
    }

    func getRealmObject() -> Realm {
        return self.realm
    }
}
```

class NotificationService(NotificationService.swift)

```
import UserNotifications
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import Realm

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

    //
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let order: Order = Order()
    //
    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

        let message = request.content.userInfo
        print("userInfo: \(message)")
        guard
            let aps = message[AnyHashable("aps")] as? NSDictionary,
            let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary,
            let title = alert["body"] as? String,
            let body = alert["title"] as? String
            else {
                // handle any error here
                return
        }
        print("Title: \(title) \nBody:\(body)")

        order.name = title
        order.amount = body

        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(order)
        }       

        if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
            // Modify the notification content here...
            bestAttemptContent.body = "\(bestAttemptContent.body) [test]"

            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }

    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }

}
```

AppDelegates.swift App running Save messages

```
let realm = try! Realm()
 let order: Order = Order()

   func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo //
        print("userInfo: \(userInfo)")
        guard
        let aps = userInfo[AnyHashable("aps")] as? NSDictionary,
        let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary,
        let body = alert["body"] as? String,
        let title = alert["title"] as? String
        else {
            // handle any error here
            return
        }
        print("Title: \(title) \nBody:\(body)")
        order.name = title
        order.amount = body
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(order)
        }
        completionHandler([.badge, .sound, .alert])
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the issue still relevant for you?
I think your problem is that the RAM of any extension is limited by the some memory value (the last value, that I know - was 12 MB). When you try to initialize the Realm, iOS unloads the extension from memory because the limit is exceeded.

In my case I was able to save data, and sometimes not, at this time the application did not crash, just the result was not achieved. But if I started debugging the extension and step through all the initialization lines step by step, I saw that after the break point in place of Realm init, the debugging mode was turned off and it indicating that the memory limit was exceeded.

To avoid this, you can specify schemas explicitly using Realm.Configuration. When giving schemas explicitly, Realm doesn't invoke objc_copyClassList(), because no need to enumerate all classes.

```
let necessaryTypes = [SomeClass.self, AnotherClass.self] 
let dataBaseURL = FileManager.default
    .containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "yourIdentifier")!
    .appendingPathComponent("default.realm")
let config = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: dataBaseURL, objectTypes: necessaryTypes) 
let realm = try Realm(configuration: config)
```